# How do we prove that $\,V(Q)=V((Q))\;?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a ring and $Q\subseteq A$ a subset. Then we define $V(Q) := \{ p \in \mathrm{Spec}(A) : Q \subseteq p \}$ where $\mathrm{Spec}(A) = \{\text{prime ideals of $A$}\}$. Now I need to show that $V(Q) = V((Q))$ where $(Q)$ denotes the ideal generated by $Q$.

$\supseteq$: Let $p \in V((Q))$, then $p \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and $(Q) \subseteq p$, so in particular $Q \subseteq p$ and hence $p \in V(Q)$.

$\subseteq$: Let $p \in V(Q)$, then $p \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and $Q \subseteq p$. The problem here is that I can’t deduce from this that $(Q) \subseteq p$. Therefore I wanted to ask if you could give me a hint how to prove this inclusion.

I know that $(Q) = \{ a_1 q_1 + \dotsb + a_n q_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, a_i \in A, q_i \in Q\}$.

Comment: What is $S$ in the definition of $V(Q)$ ?

Comment: @Angelo sorry tipo

Comment: If $Q \subset p$, are you sure you can't tell anything for the inclusion of the ideal generated by $Q$ in $p$ ? For example if $A$ was a subset of a vectorial space $V$, wouldn't you have $\mathrm{Vect}(A) \subset V$ ?

Comment: No, I mean that I bet that if you weren't talking about ideals but about a more familiar structure such as groups of vector spaces, you'd know how to prove it. Then you can adapt the idea of the proof but for ideals. (I'm not sure that I am beeing very clear)

Comment: @Zag sorry what is Vect(A), is it the vector space generated by $A$?

Comment: One way to define $(Q)$ is as the intersection of all ideals $I \supseteq Q$.  Can you prove $Q \subseteq p \implies (Q) \subseteq p$ from that?

Comment: sorry i meant $\mathrm{span}(A)$

Comment: @Zag but I mean wouldn't it be clear in the vector space situation? I don't see what I need to prove. So I mean I would need to show that every vector generated by vectors in $A$ is still in $V$ right?

Comment: @Zag but in our situation this means that I need to prove that $a_1q_1+...+a_nq_n$ is in $p$, where I know that $q_i\in p$ for all $i$

Comment: @BrianMoehring no sorry I can't

Comment: More directly, then.  Can you show $B \cap C$ is a subset of $B$?

Comment: What is an ideal for you ? If you go back to the definition, you'll see that if you take $q_1, \ldots, q_n \in Q \subset p$, it is easy to deduce that $a_1q_1 + \cdots + a_nq_n \in p$ for any $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$.

Comment: @Zag ah right I know by definition $a_iq_i\in p$, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from where you got, we have $Q \subset p $ and need to show that $(Q) \subset p$. So let $x\in (Q)$. As you've noticed yourself, we can write

$$x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iq_i$$

where $a_i \in A$ and $q_i \in Q$. Since $Q\subset p$, we have that $q_i \in p$, and since $p$ is an ideal, we have $a_iq_i \in p$, and therefore $x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iq_i \in p$, proving the inclusion.

Comment: Perhaps you should write “let $x\!\in\!(Q)$” instead of “let $q\!\in\!(Q)$”.

Comment: Oups, fixed. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;\mathcal F=\left\{I\;|\;I\text{ is an ideal of }A\;\land\;I\supseteq Q\right\}$.

Since $\;p\in V(Q)\;,\;$ then $\;p\in\mathcal F\;$ and

consequently we get that

$p\supseteq p\cap\left(\underset{I\in\mathcal F}{\cap} I\right)\underset{\overbrace{\text{in fact }p\in\mathcal F}}{=}\underset{I\in\mathcal F}{\cap} I=(Q)$

indeed $\;(Q)\;$ is the intersection of all ideals of $\,A\,$ which contain $\,Q\,.$

Hence ,

$p\supseteq(Q)\;$ and $\;p\in V((Q))\;.$